# Why additional attribute appears after the transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to copy template into the output document just as it is, but additional attribute appears at the template tag. I am using same file for the transformation input.

Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:import href="../Product/templates.xsl"/> <!--in fb changees-->
<xsl:output method="xml"/>  
    <xsl:template name="root" match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[@name='test-case-1']"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="test-case-1" >
            <test-case-1 name="koza">
                <xsl:value-of select="100"/>
            </test-case-1>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the output:

```
<xsl:template xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" name="test-case-1">
<test-case-1 name="koza">
    <xsl:value-of select="100"/>
</test-case-1>
```

What bothers me is the appearance of the `xmlns:xsl` as an attribute of the `<xsl:template>` tag.Why this namespace attribute appears in **xsl:template**?

Thank you.

**EDITION**
The output I expect is this:

```
    <xsl:template name="test-case-1">
       <test-case-1 name="koza">
          <xsl:value-of select="100"/>
       </test-case-1>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Because that's where the `xsl:` prefix is defined.

Comment: Is there approach to avoid it?

Comment: `xmlns:xls` is not an attribute, but a namespace declaration. If you are copying an element with an `xsl:` prefix, then the namespace declaration should be present. It looks like you are applying the XSLT to itself. Can you show the exact output you are expecting in this instance? Thanks!

Comment: I edited my original post with the result I expect. Thank you.

Comment: @RadoslawKrasimirow The output you expect is not allowed in XML. You cannot use a prefix without binding it to a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT output will always be namespace-well-formed. If the output contains a name with a namespace prefix, then it will always contain a declaration of that prefix.

Why do you want to produce ill-formed output?

If you want to copy/paste this output into a bigger XML document, the extra namespace declaration will do no harm. If you copy it into a bigger XML document using an XSLT transformation, the extra namespace declaration will disappear.